# Regex - ignoring text between quotes / HTML(5) attribute filtering

Tags: javascript, regex, filter, attributes, expression

So I have this [Regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/qW0yV9/1), which basically has to filter the given string to a ***HTML(5) format*** list of attributes. It currently isn't doing my fulfilling, but that's about to change! (I hope so)

I'm trying to achieve that whenever an occurrence is found, it selects the text until the next occurrence **OR** the end of the string, as the *second* match. So if you'd take a look at the current regular expression:

```
/([a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)=["']/g
```

A string like this: `hey="hey world" hey-heyhhhhh3123="Hello world" data-goed="hey"`

Would be filtered / matched out like this:

```
MATCH 1. [0-3]   `hey`
MATCH 2. [16-32] `hey-heyhhhhh3123`
MATCH 3. [47-56] `data-goed`
```

This has to be seen as the **attribute-name(s)**, and now.. we just have to fetch the attribute's **value(s)**. So the mentioned string has to have an outcome like this:

```
MATCH 1. 
         1 [0-3]     `hey`
         2 [6-14]    `hey world`
MATCH 2. 
         1 [16-32]   `hey-heyhhhhh3123`
         2 [35-45]   `Hello world`
MATCH 3. 
         1 [47-56]   `data-goed`
         2 [59-61]   `hey`
```

Could anyone try and help me to get my fulfilling? It would be appericiated a lot!

Comment: I think the best pattern here is [`/([^\s=]+)=(?:"([^"]+)"|(\S+))/g`](https://regex101.com/r/uV7oJ9/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to escape quotes in quotes / everything between the first occurrence and the next occurrence (for inlined javascript executions / functions). So I can't use your regular expression :/

Comment: Like [`([^\s=]+)=(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|(\S+))`](https://regex101.com/r/uV7oJ9/3)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exactly! Mind posting this as an answer with explanation of the regular expression? It'll the accepted answer!

Comment: @Bilal075_ Is there a reason you need to parse the HTML yourself? The browser does that pretty well already and you have access to element [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) via the DOM

Comment: @BDawg Yes there is. I'm allowing users to add attributes to a specific element. This can done due submitting a string and/or filling in a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
/([^\s=]+)=(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|(\S+))/g
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV7oJ9/3)

**Pattern details**:

- `([^\s=]+)`  - Group 1 capturing 1 or more characters other than whitespace and `=` symbol
- `=` - an equal sign
- `(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|(\S+))` - a non-capturing group of 2 alternatives (one more [`'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/uV7oJ9/4) alternative can be added to account for single quoted string literals)

  - `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` - a double quoted string literal pattern:

    - `"` - a double quote
    - `([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ characters other than `\` and `"`, followed with 0+ sequences of any escaped symbol followed with 0+ characters other than `\` and `"`
    - `"` - a closing dlouble quote
  - `|`  - or
  - `(\S+)` - Group 3 capturing one or more non-whitespace characters

JS demo (no single quoted support):

```js
var re = /([^\s=]+)=(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|(\S+))/g; 
var str = 'hey="hey world" hey-heyhhhhh3123="Hello \\"world\\"" data-goed="hey" more=here';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m[3]) {
      res.push([m[1], m[3]]);
    } else {
      res.push([m[1], m[2]]);
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

JS demo (with single quoted literal support)

```js
var re = /([^\s=]+)=(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'|(\S+))/g; 
var str = 'pseudoprefix-before=\'hey1"\' data-hey="hey\'hey" more=data and="more \\"here\\""';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m[2]) {
    res.push([m[1], m[2]])
  } else if (m[3]) {
    res.push([m[1], m[3]])
  } else if (m[4]) {
    res.push([m[1], m[4]])
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! However.. is it possible to ignore *EVERYTHING* inside the value field? Take a look at this example: https://regex101.com/r/tP1aY6/1 . Note the tollerance of quotes (when using thick quotes, single quotes must be escaped and the opposite of when using single quotes, double quotes must be escaped).

Comment: I provided a regex for the 3 scenarios. It should be a separate alternation branch. I will add a snippet. See https://regex101.com/r/tP1aY6/2. The answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Now it's just a little bit of stunting with unexpected matches (receiving a couple keys with as value undefined). But I can't thank you enough for your time!

Comment: I have no other way to contact you, than putting up this comment.. Is it true that alternatives (if they're not used), returns undefined? Cause it seems like that's happening in the last snippet you've posted. I've read something about having a captured subpattern. But that's not the case in this regular expression, is it?

Comment: Sure, that's why I posted my snippet to show you how you can check if the group matched or not, and based on that you build the output array/list/whatver.

Comment: I've seen that. But in my mentioned regular expression *(the one I mentioned in the question)* it didn't affect the undefined / not found sections. Is there any reason that causes this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122117/discussion-between-bilal075-and-wiktor-stribizew).